# Deploy ServerSocket application

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I must implement a small server app in JAVA like this:

```
public class ServerSimple {
    private Socket  socket   = null;
    private ServerSocket    server   = null;
    public ServerSimple(int port)   {   
        try {  
            server = new ServerSocket(port);  
            socket = server.accept();
            open();
```

But I wonder where I can deploy this small socket server (with public IP address). I try AWS EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk, but it’s only for tomcat application isn't it ? It’s possible with AWS ?

I’m using Eclipse & Git.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not even for tomcat.
You are re-inventing the wheel.

When you code a class like that, assuming that you are going to be something like an HTTP server, or whatever, you essentially are making a stand alone java application.

How do you deploy that?
What about:
java my.main.java.file -claspatth whatever.jar;myApplication.jar;depends.jar;upon.jar

When you deploy code to an application server, whetther full-fleged Java EE container (e.g. glassfish) or not (e.g. tomcat), you let the server handle the low level apis, such as new ServerSocket(port).
You just code what comes after, when a request comes in, e.g. by coding http servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Nanohttpd. It is open source, lightweight implementation of http server.